# How to map table in ODI 11 if this table not exist yet

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a situation here that I do not know what to do.

I have a table in the source system of my ETL that is created by the system at the end of the month. The table name is like `Table_MM_YYYY`, where `MM_YYYY` is the month and year.

I need to map this table and use it in an ODI interface.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is possible by using variables in the ODI. That is, if you do not change the table structure then in the Source table substitute the name of the variable, and already in the variable will be the name of the table. In the variable, put the name of the table created at the end of the month according to the capacity of the request or procedure. I think that gave some impetus. Watch this link it like what you need with file only [watch this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/using-variables-in-odi:-creating-a-loop-in-a-package)